# any video playback is frozen until pulseaudio -k is used

Tags: audio

I'm using fedora 35, and have hard time watching videos on my desktop after upgrade (34 -> 35). Everytime I play the video in the browser and then pause to check something in other tab or console - the resume never works

If I run `pulseaudio -k` in the console - the video continues, but it is really annoying.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Did your newer question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696851/pulseaudio-makes-videos-in-the-browser-frozen) answer this one as well?  It sounds similar to me.

Comment: yes I did fix it.